# 0.96" OLED and Arduino UNO usage error

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, compile, display

I have Arduino UNO with 0.96" OLED display with 128(width)*32(height). It is said that I have to edit Adafruit_SSD1306.h for my 128*32 OLED, okey I did it from 128*64 to 128*32 but I still get the compiler error:

```
ssd1306_128x32_i2c.ino:54:2: error: #error ("Height incorrect, please
fix Adafruit_SSD1306.h!");
```

Yes, I fixed the Adafruit_SSD1306.h file, **but now,** it is still gives me a compiler error:

```
C:\Users\OB\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\utility/twi.h: In member
function 'uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)':
C:\Users\OB\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\utility/twi.h:47: error:
too many arguments to function 'uint8_t twi_readFrom(uint8_t,
uint8_t*, uint8_t)'
C:\Users\OB\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp:85: error: at
this point in file
C:\Users\OB\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\utility/twi.h: In member
function 'uint8_t TwoWire::endTransmission(uint8_t)':
C:\Users\OB\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\utility/twi.h:48: error:
too many arguments to function 'uint8_t twi_writeTo(uint8_t, uint8_t*,
uint8_t, uint8_t)'
C:\Users\OB\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp:140: error: at
this point in file
C:\Users\OB\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp: In member
function 'virtual size_t TwoWire::write(const uint8_t*, size_t)':
C:\Users\OB\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp:195: error:
invalid conversion from 'const uint8_t*' to 'uint8_t*'
C:\Users\OB\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp:195: error:  
initializing argument 1 of 'uint8_t twi_transmit(uint8_t*, uint8_t)'
```

[image]
[image]

How can I use my four-pin OLED display with no errors?

Comment: It looks like the code you are trying to use may require a different version of the twi library.

Comment: Do you have the proper pullup's enabled on the I2C interface? Also some of the I2C displays have a different control chip so it's not identical to the Adafruit one. Verify which display controller is used on your board if you can. If that is good looks like your sketch i still struggling with the I2C setup. Says too many arguments are being used.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: Yes, I have already made it so perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I hope I'm not late. Try to use arduino 1.0.6.

Comment: Do you have I2C pull-ups in place? I don't see them on your breadboard.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the following. I found this fork of the Adafruit library which works better than the one they have on their website [Adafruit_ssd1306syp](https://github.com/Miyeah/Arduino-Dormitory-Assistant/tree/master/library/Adafruit_ssd1306syp). The original `Adafruit_ssd1306` library doesn't play nice with SPI and when you want to have your OLED running on i2c and use the SPI for something else. This is a great resource. Download, unzip to your libraries directory. Then run this sketch:

```
#include <Adafruit_ssd1306syp.h>

#define SDA_PIN A4
#define SCL_PIN A5

Adafruit_ssd1306syp display(SDA_PIN, SCL_PIN);

void setup() {

  display.initialize();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  printM("Starting Demo...");

}

void printM(String mess) {

  display.println(mess);
  display.update();
}

void loop() {

  printM("working");
  delay(1000);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may wanna try this lib: https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib

Supports many devices and is very well documented!

Cheers